# Why does this Javascript function return "Undefined" when called?

Tags: javascript

I've written the following simple JavaScript code. But whenever I run it, it displays "Undefined" as a result.

Following is the code:

```
function naturalSum(num1,num2) {
    var sumValue = 0;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if (i%num1 === 0 || i%num2 === 0) {
            sumValue += i ;    
        }
    }
}
document.write(naturalSum(3,5));
```

I want to know why this is happening. When I'm not enclosing the code within the function, the code's working fine. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: have you not posted the `return` call, or is that your problem

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript functions return undefined by default, unless you explicitly return something.

So, if you want your function to return `sumValue`, you should add `return sumValue;` as the function’s last line:

```
function naturalSum(num1,num2) {
    var sumValue = 0;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if (i%num1 === 0 || i%num2 === 0) {
            sumValue += i ;
        }
    }
    return sumValue;
}
```

[@AmitJoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001736/amit-joki) created a JSFiddle to demonstrate:

- http://jsfiddle.net/dgC46/

Comment: hi, I just created a fiddle, when your answer sprang up. can you include it please ? The url is http://jsfiddle.net/dgC46/

Answer (score 1):

```
function naturalSum(num1,num2) 
{
    var sumValue = 0;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if (i%num1 === 0 || i%num2 === 0) 
        {
            sumValue += i ;
        }
    }
    //You forgot to return the value
    return sumValue;
}
document.write(naturalSum(3,5));
```

Comment: Yup, problem solved. However, I have one more question. I used the return keyword with like this:

function naturalSum(num1,num2) 
{
    var sumValue = 0;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if (i%num1 === 0 || i%num2 === 0) 
        {
            return sumValue += i ;
        }
    }
    
}
document.write(naturalSum(3,5));

But then the editor was displaying an error that the return stating that the function does not always return a value. 

I want to ask that why is this happening?

Comment: @saadi123: I suspect it’s because you put your return statement within an `if` statement, so it’ll only get called when the `if`’s condition is true.

Comment: @Dennington-bear: this from Pedant’s Corner: a return statement outside the `if` but inside the `for` would make the function return the first time the for loop runs. It would never increment, because the return statement would have made the function return before it got a chance.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite
Thanks for the guidance.